# How to save open tabs in IE 8 to favourites using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I've got like 60 webpages + several tabs in each one open in IE 8 and I want to add them all to favourites without doing each page individually. Is it possible to do with just keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Alt-A opens the Favorites menu, arrow down twice selects Add current tabs to favorites..., and then you're set.

There is not specific command for this. But as you can see, it can be done with just a few keystrokes.

Microsoft has a webpage that shows [all the key commands for IE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Internet-Explorer-keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: But I have to press Alt-A for each window open, yes? I've got multiple IE windows with several tabs per window.

Comment: I suppose you would. But it's still faster than doing each tab individually. Not perfect, just a little better.